# How PHP script can be called using Java Applet

Tags: java, php, applet

I want to access user's scanner using PHP script. I know this can be done by using PHP script on Linux based machine.

I want to put this script on the server and wanted to run it via Java Applet I don't know Java much also I am not sure if this task can be done by this way.

Please suggest if this is correct way and How to proceed on it.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Can the scanner PHP code be operated purely via parameters in the URL? If so, then a Java applet could connect to those URLs passing parameters as necessary, and if the PHP script returns information in the HTML output stream (as if it were returning a web page), then the applet can parse the page it 'downloads' from that URL to get the information out. Not elegant, but do-able.